# Is there a selector that handles "the element contains an element with class"

Tags: css, sass

I have HTML like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="email" class="form-control>
    <div class="form-error">This is not valid email address</div>
</div>
```

I am printing `div.form-error` dynamically if the input has errors.

I need CSS code to make the input's border red if there is a `div.form-error` in the `div.form-group`.

I'am working with SASS, maybe it has a function to do this. I'm looking for a something like this:

```
.form-group {
    &:contains('.form-error') {
        input {
            border: 1px solid red;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'd be tempted to put the `form-error` (or an alternative class-name) on the `.form-group` element itself, rather than on its child (I'm assuming the addition of the class-name is done using either a server-side script or with JavaScript on the client-side, either of which could handle this). Unfortunately, however, with pure CSS it's not possible to style an ancestor (or previous sibling) based on its descendant (or subsequent sibling).

Comment: Adding a class to the parent would be much easier since you can easily control everything in the child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so while my comment still stands – it is not possible to use CSS to style a previous sibling, or ancestor, based on a subsequent sibling or descendant – there is a way around it. Though it while it *does* require a change of your HTML it will still emulate the element-order that you posted in your question.

That said, the HTML is changed from the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" />
  <div class="form-error">This is not valid email address</div>
</div>
```

To:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-error">This is not valid email address</div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

```css
.form-group {
  /* to use the flex layout model: */
  display: flex;

  /* to have the elements arranged
     in a column instead of a row
     (which you may or may not want): */
  flex-direction: column;

  /* aesthetics, adjust to taste: */
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
}

.form-group .form-error {
  /* places the .form-error element(s)
     at the end of the layout in position
     2, which causes the <input> to take
     position 1; note that the elements
     are still in the same place for CSS
     selection: */
  order: 2;
}


/* This styles the email <input> element if
   it follows the .form-error element: */
.form-error + input[type=email] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-error">This is not a valid email address</div>
  <input type="email" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Incidentally it's worth noting that according to [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox), flexbox is available in all current browsers; though your users may not have updated their own browsers to the current (or previous) version as of writing.

There are, of course, other ways you can achieve this simply using the `:invalid` pseudo-class:

```css
/* Selects any <input> element whose value is invalid: */
input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" />
  <div class="form-error">This is not a valid email address</div>
</div>
```

And, of course, you can even use fading to show or hide the error message:

```css
/* Selects any <input> element whose value is invalid: */

input:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

/* hides the .form-error element using the opacity
   property which takes a value, which allows it
   to be animated from hidden (opacity: 0) to shown
   (opacity: 1): */
.form-error {
  /* visually hidden: */
  opacity: 0;
  /* specifies that the opacity property should be
     transitioned over a 0.3 second time in a linear
     animation: */
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}
/* Selects the .form-error element that immediately
   follows an <input> which is :invalid */
input:invalid+.form-error {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" />
  <div class="form-error">This is not a valid email address</div>
</div>
```

Bibliography:

- "[Using CSS Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)."

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out correctly by folks in the comments, you will need to alter mark up for this to work. You can use the `sibling` selector:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```
.form-group {
    .form-error + input {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

```css
.form-error + input {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-error">This is not valid email address</div>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: I think the `+` selector will only work if the `.form-error` is _immediately_ before the `input`, which in the provided markup its after not before.

Comment: "*There's also the general sibling selector for going back up the tree*" - no, no there isn't: *nothing*, no combinator at all, as yet, will "*go back up the tree*."

Comment: I've reworded for clarity. I've used this before for form elements - for example styling a label for a focused input.

Comment: `.form-error + input` would target the input IF it is after the form-error, the same goes for `~` https://jsfiddle.net/njfcocpx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) and [sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors).

For your example:

```
.form-group {
    .form-error ~ input {
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the general-sibling combinator works differently in SASS, somehow, because if not that shouldn't work.

Comment: On the link provided for sibling selector, it clearly shows that the target needs to be after and not before. so `.form-error ~ input` would not work since the input is before the error https://jsfiddle.net/njfcocpx/1/